# Updating controls in 2nd Window

Tags: xcode, cocoa-bindings

I have two windows, 1 **mainMenu** and 1 **window** added by me

i open the 2nd window after clicking on a button on **mainMenu** Window using

```
myWindowController *w = [[myWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindow" owner:self]];
[w showWindow:self];
```

i have public method in **myWindowController** which populates all the controls

```
[w.populateControls];
```

if i populate the controls from window2 **awakeFromNib** the controls display ok

but **not** from

```
[w.populateControls];   // in mainMenu
```

what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Does this actually compile: `[w.populateControls];`?  Also, `populateControls` is not the same as `PopulateControls`.

Comment: populateControls vs PopulateControls,  it is just a typo, yes it does compile and populateControls is being called, i checked using the debugger

Comment: Interesting.  If I put a property-style dotted reference inside square brackets with no method, the compiler gives me an "Expected identifier" error.

Comment: i mentioned in my initial posting that **populateControls** method is in another class (**windowController**)

Comment: Right, but the `w.populateControls` syntax is for reading a property, not for calling an explicit method so my confusion is about what it's doing inside `[]` all by itself.

Comment: sorry, it should have been   **[w populateControls];**

Comment: Ah...then check the values of `w` in both cases to see that they're pointing to the same object address (and that it's not null).